# Postgres combine update query

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a a simple update query:

```
UPDATE
  FOO
SET
  bar = true
WHERE
  id in (1,2,3....)
```

how can i combine this with the exact opposite

```
UPDATE
  FOO
SET
  bar = false
WHERE
  id NOT in (1,2,3....)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the `in` clause into the `set` part:

```
update foo
   set bar = (id in (1,2,3, ...));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output can achieve by the `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE FOO SET bar = ( CASE WHEN id IN (1, 2, 3....) THEN true
                            WHEN id NOT IN (1, 2, 3....) THEN false
                            ELSE NULL END )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize conditional statements in `UPDATE` queries in Postgres: [Conditional statements in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-conditional.html).

The `UPDATE` statement could be written in the form below:

```
UPDATE
  FOO
SET
  bar = CASE WHEN id IN (1, 2, 3...)
  THEN true
  ELSE false
  END
```